# Angular JS Data table - Alphanumeric sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, datatables

I'm currently using angular-datatables and I'm not able to sort the rows correctly. I have an alphanumeric field to be sorted as follows:

```
1
2
3
4a
4b
11
13a
13b.
```

But when I use datatable sorting, it sorts in the following manner:

```
1
11
13a
13b
2
3
4a.
```

I tried using the natural sort plug-in for datatables but still getting the same output. How can I sort alphanumeric values in datatables using angularjs?

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 0):

That is the alphanumerical order what you are getting, JavaScript sort function it's comparing the values (text) letter by letter, so 11 > 2 because the first letter were compared and the 1 is grater than the 2.

So if you want another order I think you have to write your own algorithm (function).